# I want to list Install and Upgrade package list with date and repo name

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, repository

I want to list Install and Upgrade package list with date and repo nam.

I have multiple repo in my server some i want scan and list daily what are package install and when it installed and which repo used for it. any help please .

what i required here i did in RHEL by using below the commands, same like i need in Ubuntu could you please some one help here.

```
repoquery -a --installed --qf "%{ui_from_repo} | %{name} | %{release} | %{INSTALLTIME}" | grep '^@MY_REPONAME' |  awk -F "|" '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", $4)}' | sort -t '|' -k1  | tail -1`
```

### Sample output.

Packagename | Repo_Name | Installed_date

Answer (score 0):

The apt and dpkg databases on your Ubuntu system do not keep track of dates. Debian-based systems therefore do not have a comparable apt command.

The information is on your system in your apt logs (/var/log/apt/). You must build a script to parse those logs and present the data in your preferred output format.

Please remember to share your script with others, so they can use it, too.

Comment: Thanks for the update ! i Build the script and it working. will keep post on here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of my question, We need to work some tricky type of action.

Step-1 : Collect Installed and Update package based on the date.

```
for x in $(ls -1t /var/log/dpkg.log*);do zcat -f $x |tac |grep -e " install " -e " upgrade "; done | awk -F ":a" '{print $1 " :a" $2}' | column -t | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$4" "$7}' | grep -i "2021-12-18" > /tmp/pkg.list
```

Step-2: Do some loop to get repo name based on the package name which we copied /tmp/pkg.list file .

```
cat /tmp/pkg.list | while read a b c d ; do repo=`apt-cache showpkg $c | grep $d | head -1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed -r 's/(\(|\))//g'`; echo $a $b $c $d $repo;done
```